# What's wrong with my jquery-ajax code so it's not working properly?

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

Following is my HTML code from Smarty template :

```
<div id="user-popup-login" title="Demo Test Packages">
  <div id="pop-up">
    <!--<div class="popup-right"><img src="images_new/close.gif" alt=" " align="right" width="29" height="29" /></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>-->
    <div class="error_msg" id="login_error" style="text-align:center; margin-top:5px;">

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="popup-left">
      <form name="user_login_form" id="user_login_form" class="login_box" method="post" action="{$site_url}login">
      <input type="hidden" name="referral_url" value="{$referral_url}" id="referral_url" />
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input name="user_name" id="user_name" class="user" type="text" value="E-mail" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='E-mail';" onfocus="if(this.value=='E-mail') this.value='';" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input name="user_password" id="user_password" class="user" type="password" value="password" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='password';" onfocus="if(this.value=='password') this.value='';" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="login-btn" value="" /></td>
            <td><div id="registern"><a href="#" class="register-btn">Register Now</a></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="2"><a href="{$site_url}forgot_password.php?op=forget_password" class="forget">Forgot Password? </a> &nbsp; </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="popup-right"><img src="images_new/facebook-sign.gif" alt=" " width="156" height="229" /></div>-->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is my jQuery code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {  
  $("#user-popup-login").dialog({ autoOpen: false }); 
  $( ".user-not-loggedin" )
    .click(function() {
    $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "option", "width", 400 );
    $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "option", "modal", true );
    $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "open" );

    return false;
  });

  $( ".get-start" )
    .click(function() {
    $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "option", "width", 400 );
    $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "option", "modal", true );
    $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "open" );

    return false;
  });     

  //This function is used to submit User Login form
  $('#user_login_form').live('submit', function() { 
     $('.login-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     show_request('#login_error');
      $.ajax({   
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'), 
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) { 
          $('.login-btn').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
          var log_error = response.log_error;

          if(log_error=='yes') { 
            var error_msg      = response.error_msg; 
            var dialog_title   = 'Input Errors Found';                 
            var dialog_message = error_msg; 
            $("#login_error").html(error_msg);
          } else { 
            $("#login_error").html('');
            $( "#user-login" ).dialog('close');
            var suc_msg   = response.suc_msg; 
            var dialog_title   = 'Logged in Successfully';                 
            var dialog_message = suc_msg; 

            var $dialog = $("<div class='ui-state-success'></div>")
            .html("<p class='ui-state-error-success'>"+dialog_message+"</p>")
            .dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               modal:true,
               title: dialog_title,
               width: 500,               
               buttons:{
               'OK': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                 }
               }                               
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open'); 
            $('#user_login_form')[0].reset();  
          }

        } 
      });    
      return false;
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

And my php file named user_login.php which has an alas name as login which is used in action attribute has following code :

```
<?php
  include_once("includes/application-header.php");

    prepare_request();

  $obj_login = new Login();

  if($gSession->ReadFromSession('IS_LOGGEDIN') && $_GET['act'] !='logout') {
    header("location:".SITE_URL."home");
        die();
  } else {    
      if( "POST" == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) { 
            $login_data = extract_array( $_POST , array("user_name", "user_password") );
            $user_id = $obj_login->DoUserLogin($login_data);

            if($user_id) {
                list($subscription_type, $days_left) = $gUsers->GetUserSubscriptionDetailsByUserID($user_id);

                if($gUsers->InitiateUserSession($user_id, $subscription_type, $days_left)) {
                    $gUsers->UpdateUserLoginHistory($user_id);
                    $reponse_data['login_error'] = 'no';
                    $reponse_data = json_encode($reponse_data);
                    echo $reponse_data;
                    die();
                }
            } else {
                $error_msg =  $obj_login->GetError();
                list($login_data) = prepare_response($login_data);
                $error_msg = '<b>We are unable to log you in for one of the following reasons:</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <ul>
                                            <li>Incorrect email or password (case sensitive)</li>
                                            <li>Cookies are not enabled on your browser</li>
                                            <li>You havent registered with entrance prime</li>
                                            <li>We have not activated your account</li>
                                            </ul><p></p>';
                $reponse_data['login_error'] = 'yes';
                $reponse_data['error_msg'] = $error_msg;
                $reponse_data = json_encode($reponse_data);
                echo $reponse_data;    
                die();
            }
      }

      // CODE FOR LOGOUT
      if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act']=='logout') {
            $gUsers->UpdateUserLogoutHistory();
          $obj_login->UserLogout();

          header("Location:".SITE_URL."home");
          die();
      }
  }
?>
```

My issue is when a I click on Login button without filling any values,the form is submitted without any error and displays "undefined" in the pop-up instead of showing me the errors. Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `live` was removed in v1.9. Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console of your browser?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes I know that. I'm using jQuery 1.4.1 which supports live. So I'm not getting any error for that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Unfortunately it's not possible. I've to work with 1.4.1 only for now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes, I'm not getting any errors. If you looked at code
 if(log_error=='yes') { 
                      } else {
The control is always going into else part instead of going into if part and display errors. The errors should be received from the php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in php , --> login_error

```
$reponse_data['login_error'] = 'no';
```

in ajas  callback    --->log_error

```
      var log_error = response.log_error;
```

try to change all  log_error to login_error

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake. As per your suggestion I did the change and it worked for me. You saved my much precious time. I've marked this as correct answer and also increased your points. Once again Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that $(this) inside of $.ajax does not point to the $ object you want it to (form).

Try writing just below this line:

```
$('#user_login_form').live('submit', function() {
    myform = $(this); // caching the jquery object to a local variable
```

and then writing this in the proper section below (replace your code):

```
$.ajax({   
        type: myform.attr('method'),
        url: myform.attr('action'), 
        data:myform.serialize(),
```

Comment: No, that's incorrect. `this` will refer to the form. It wouldn't inside one of the `ajax` *callbacks*, but at the point the options object is being created, that's still the event handler function, and so `this` is still the form. `$.ajax({/*...*/})` first *creates* the options object (`{/*...*/}`), and *then* calls the function. It's exactly like `var o = {/*...*/}; $.ajax(o);`

Comment: I tried your trick but still the erroras are not getting displayed and the pop up with text "undefined" is getting displayed.